# Delete Query Inside While Loop

Tags: php, mysql, twitter-bootstrap, mysqli, while-loop

i'm trying to delete database record inside a while loop. I'm showing my user list in a table with while loop. I have a button, bootstrap modal opening a modal window. In that window i have submit to delete button. With while loop.
Problem is, i'm trying to delete this record, but its deleting random record. can you check is there a problem?

Thanks already.
here is my code:

```
<table class="table table-hover">
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th>Id</th>
        <th>Name</th>
        <th>Surname</th>
        <th>Email</th>
        <th>Password</th>
        <th>*</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>


<?php

    $q = "SELECT * FROM users";
    $r = mysqli_query($dbc,$q);
    while($list = mysqli_fetch_assoc($r)){
        if(isset($_POST['del_submit'])){
            $q = "DELETE FROM users WHERE id = '$list[id]' ";
            $r = mysqli_query($dbc, $q);
                 header('Location: index.php?page=7');
            }

        echo '<tr>';
        echo '<td>'.$list['id'].'</td>';
        echo '<td>'.$list['name'].'</td>';
        echo '<td>'.$list['surname'].'</td>';
        echo '<td>'.$list['email'].'</td>';
        echo '<td>'.$list['password'].'</td>';
        echo '<td><button class="btn btn-danger btn-xs" data-toggle="modal" data-target=".delete'.$list['id'].'"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-trash" aria-hidden="true"></span></button> ';

        echo '</tr><form method="post" action="#">';         
        echo '<div class="modal fade delete'.$list['id'].'">
              <div class="modal-dialog modal-sm" role="document">
                <div class="modal-content">             
                    <div class="modal-header">
                    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
                    <h4 class="modal-title">Delete <strong class="text-primary">'.$list['name'].' ?</strong></h4>
                    </div>

                    <div class="modal-body">
                    <strong class="text-primary">'.$list['name'].' '.$list['surname'].'</strong><br>
                    Are you Sure?
                    </div>
                    <div class="modal-footer">
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Cancel</button>

                    <button type="submit" name="del_submit" id="del_submit" class="btn btn-danger"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-trash" aria-hidden="true"></span> Delete</button>
                    </div>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div></form>'; 

    }
?>




    </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: Have you checked your error logs? You're making an assumption the query is working.
Add error reporting to the top of your file(s) right after your opening `<?php` tag `error_reporting(E_ALL); ini_set('display_errors', 1);`

Comment: I think it removes the last one record, or not? It's strange to remove items into the select loop. Delete records using condition `where id = (int)$_POST['id']` instead of nonsense like `$list['id']` - don't forget to add hidden input with ID into your HTML.

Comment: its deleting first id in the list. For example first id = 1 second =2 ... fourth:4
for example: if i click third delete button, its deleting first record.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

i will first acknowledge that your script is not safe and efficient this way. Why not handle delete operations with Ajax and call to a different script?
You have to pass the value of the id with the delete button and then use the id value you passed with the button instead.
For your delete button inside the modal add value attribute

```
<button type="submit" name="del_submit" value="'.$list['id'].'" id="del_submit" class="btn btn-danger"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-trash" aria-hidden="true"></span> Delete</button>
```

Then retrieve the id and use the id. Its should work

```
if(isset($_POST['del_submit'])){
    $listItemID = $_POST['del_submit'];
    $q = "DELETE FROM users WHERE id = '$listItemID' ";
    $r = mysqli_query($dbc, $q);
        header('Location: index.php?page=7');
}
```

If where you are redirecting the user is with the id of the deleted element simply use

`header('Location: index.php?page=$listItemID'); instead of header('Location: index.php?page=7');

Full code becomes

```
<table class="table table-hover">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Id</th>
            <th>Name</th>
            <th>Surname</th>
            <th>Email</th>
            <th>Password</th>
            <th>*</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>


        <?php

        $q = "SELECT * FROM users";
        $r = mysqli_query($dbc,$q);
        while($list = mysqli_fetch_assoc($r)){
            if(isset($_POST['del_submit'])){
                $listItemID = $_POST['del_submit'];
                $q = "DELETE FROM users WHERE id = '$listItemID' ";
                $r = mysqli_query($dbc, $q);
                header('Location: index.php?page=7');
            }

            echo '<tr>';
            echo '<td>'.$list['id'].'</td>';
            echo '<td>'.$list['name'].'</td>';
            echo '<td>'.$list['surname'].'</td>';
            echo '<td>'.$list['email'].'</td>';
            echo '<td>'.$list['password'].'</td>';
            echo '<td><button class="btn btn-danger btn-xs" data-toggle="modal" data-target=".delete'.$list['id'].'"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-trash" aria-hidden="true"></span></button> ';

            echo '</tr><form method="post" action="#">';         
            echo '<div class="modal fade delete'.$list['id'].'">
              <div class="modal-dialog modal-sm" role="document">
                <div class="modal-content">             
                    <div class="modal-header">
                    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
                    <h4 class="modal-title">Delete <strong class="text-primary">'.$list['name'].' ?</strong></h4>
                    </div>

                    <div class="modal-body">
                    <strong class="text-primary">'.$list['name'].' '.$list['surname'].'</strong><br>
                    Are you Sure?
                    </div>
                    <div class="modal-footer">
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Cancel</button>

                    <button type="submit" name="del_submit" value="'.$list['id'].'" id="del_submit" class="btn btn-danger"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-trash" aria-hidden="true"></span> Delete</button>
                    </div>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div></form>'; 

        }
        ?>




    </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: The delete query is using unchecked/unsanitized user supplied data - this is bad/insecure practice.  Writing iterated DELETE queries is bad/inefficient/illogical practice.  If `$listItemID` is an integer, it doesn't need to be single quote wrapped.  I don't think anyone should be learning from the advice in this code.  You are calling `header()` after outputing to screen.

Answer (score 1):

Create a delete page and link to it.
first you need to add link to the same page with `action` and `id` parameters

```
<?php
// replace 
?>
<button type="submit" name="del_submit" id="del_submit" class="btn btn-danger"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-trash" aria-hidden="true"></span> Delete</button>
<?php
// with this: 
?>
<input type='hidden' name='id' value='<?= $list['id']; ?>'>
<input type='hidden' name='action' value='delete'>
<button class="btn btn-danger" type='submit'><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-trash" aria-hidden="true"></span> Delete</button>
```

add this to the top of your page

```
<?php

if(isset($_POST['id'], $_POST['action']) && $_POST['action'] === 'delete')              
{ 
   $id = $_POST['id'];
   $query = 'DELETE FROM `users` WHERE `id` = ?';
   $db = new Mysqli('localhost','user','password','database');
   $stmt   = $db->prepare($query);
   $stmt->bind_param('i',$id);
   $stmt->execute();
   $stmt->close();
   $db->close();
   echo 'Deleted! (if exists)';
}
```

Comment: thnks but i need to make this in same page

Comment: fixed if you can add it to the top of your page now

Comment: Passing the id to be deleted via `$_GET` is a bad idea.  If a robot/crawler finds this url pattern and decides to crawl these links, you table data will be unexpected purged for you.  Use `$_POST`.  If you are going bother casting an `(int)` then a prepared statement is overkill.  FYI, `isset()` can receive multiple parameter and maintain the same logic.  Prefixing the column name with `\`users\`.` is not necessary when only one table is being processed.

Comment: @mickmackusa such a page should be protected from crawlers ( authentication required ) , anyways i have updated my answer, i removed the integer casting and kept the prepared statement